# How do I restart a wget download?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I use the `wget` application. One file has stopped downloading. How can I stop the download and start the download again?

Here's the log for `wget`

```
$ tail -f wget-log
287350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  104K 4h46m
287400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%   101K 4h46m
287450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  106K 4h46m
287500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  102K   4h46m
287550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  102K 4h46m
287600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  104K 4h46m
287650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  102K 4h46m
287700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39% 54.8K 4h46m
287750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  101K 4h46m
287800K .......... ........
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can stop downloading a file from `wget` just by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> in the terminal.

And to continue the stopped download, just type the following in the same directory where you were downloading the file:

```
wget -c <your download url>
```

For more information about the `wget`, type following in the terminal:

```
wget -h
```

or

```
man wget
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will only work if the server supports `Range` headers.